# jQuery css selector quirk

Tags: jquery

**Background:**

I have a CMS tool that allows users to create a table inside the content area.  If the option for a border is used, the tool sets the border attribute on the table, and does not use a style.  My reset stylesheet defaults all tables to no border, and this overrides the table border attribute (i.e., no border is displayed).

As a quick hack, I put in some jQuery to grab table elements that have a non-0 border attribute and convert the border attribute into an inline style.

**My question:**

While I was able to get the code to work, it is not the solution I originally intended.

This is currently working:

```
    $("table[border!='0']").css('border', function() { 
         return $(this).attr('border') + "px solid"; 
    });
```

My original solution was to not require the function in the css method -

```
$("table[border!='0']").css('border', $(this).attr('border') + "px solid");
```

I realize as I write this question that $(this) doesn't refer to each item in the selection, as it does inside the function, thus my problem.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMan5/3/)

Is there a way to accomplish this without the function?

Comment: The code you posted cannot work since `.attr` is a function so `.attr['border']` is undefined.

Comment: Using a function as the second param to CSS looks to me like the correct and classy way of doing this. You can always split it up into multiple lines to avoid a function, but then since you are working with a collection of objects, that'll be a pain. In short, your current way is imo the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using the function is the only (and best) way since otherwise you cannot access every item separately.

Note that your code contains a bug: `$(this).attr['border']` should be `$(this).attr('border')` - otherwise you always get `undefinedpx solid` which doesn't make much sense.

However, as long as you don't have a ton of different values for `border` you could use CSS:

```css
table[border=1] { border: 1px solid; }
table[border=2] { border: 2px solid; }
```

Obviously this would be messy with many different values but chances are good that you don't have many different border widths.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the typo - I had it correct on my site, just didn't retype it correctly.

Comment: I like the CSS approach - that's probably better, rather than running code on every page load.